# Pandas incorrectly reading nested ordereddict with len 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to load an ordered dict into a pandas dataframe:

```
dataODict = OrderedDict(
    [
        ('id', '*****'), 
        ('field1', '*****'), 
        ('field2', OrderedDict(
            [
                ('id', '*****'),
                ('field1', '*****')
            ]
        )),
        ('field3', '*****'),
        ('field4', '*****'),
        ('field5', '*****')
    ]
)
```

However

```
pd.Dataframe(dataODict)
```

yields:

```
          id    field1  ...   field5
id      *****   ******        ******
field11 *****   ******        ******
```

when what I want is

```
      id    field1  field2            ... field5
id  *****   ******  OrderedDict(xxxx)     ******
```

```
pd.Dataframe(dataODict, columns=dataOdict.keys())
```

yields the same result. Does anyone know how to successfully load an ordered dict with the field structure given, but with possibly multiple records into a dataframe successfully? Just using the pandas "Dataframe" method seems to work when the len is >1 but it is incorrectly identifying the index and duplicating the record in the case I described in this post.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your dict around a list, then each item is interpreted as a row:

```
pd.DataFrame([dataODict])
```

Output:

```
      id field1                              field2 field3 field4 field5
0  *****  *****  {'id': '*****', 'field1': '*****'}  *****  *****  *****
```